# Random Dictionary Login System Python

Tags: python, login-system

I want to create the login system that will use random dictionary.The problem is accessing the elements of the dictionary after making it select random elements.I will continue trying to find the answer, but I want to post this problem here as there could be someone else with the similar problem and this could help them, and you may answer before I find the right way of access.

```
import time
import random
import string

d = {
    'l1' : 'p1', 'l2' : 'p2'
}

d1 = random.choice(list(l.items()))

def d2(l, p):
    d_l = print(l)
    d_p = input("Enter the Answer: ")

    if d_p == p:
        print("Login Successful.")
    else:
        print("Your Answer was not correct.")
        print("Process will be terminated")
        time.sleep(5)

d2(#Here is the Problem)
```

I tried accessing using `iter`, although I know it's impossible.

Comment: Question isn't clear, could you please add expected behavior as well? what exactly is L?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this Problem is:

```
import time
import random

d = {
    'l1' : 'p1', 'l2' : 'p2'
}

key, value = random.choice(list(d.items()))
def d2(l, p):
    d_l = print(l)
    d_p = input("Enter the Answer: ")

    if d_p == p:
        print("Login Successful.")
    else:
        print("Your Answer isn't correct.")
        print("Process will be terminated")
        time.sleep(5)

d2(key, value)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def getlogins():
  from requests import get
  return get(url).text

logins = getlogins()
logins = logins[:-1]
username = input("Username:")
username = str(username)
password = input("Password: ")
password = str(password)

if password == logins[username]:
    print("Logged in!")
else:
    print("Wrong password or username")
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and your other answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```py
def getlogins(url):
    from requests import get
    return get(url).text

logins = getlogins()
logins = logins[:-1]
username = input("Username:")
username = str(username)
password = input("Password: ")
password = str(password)

if password == logins[username]:
    print("Logged in!")
else:
    print("Wrong password or username")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).